# WINDIR environment variable resolves to %SystemRoot% and not C:\windows

Tags: windows, environment-variables

Some time ago I manually changed the `WINDIR` environment variable to test something in a legacy program I was working with (should have done this on a VM rather than my desktop :/ but it's too late now)

So for some reason now `%WINDIR%` does not resolve to c:\windows anymore, but to %SystemRoot%. From the command line:

```
echo %WINDIR% outputs %SystemRoot%
```

and

```
echo %SystemRoot% outputs C:\windows
```

Not being able to resolve WINDIR is causing me all sorts of head aches. I've tried setting the value of `WINDIR` explicitly to `c:\windows` in that console windows provides, but to no avail. I've also tried manually changing the windir registry key's value at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment\windier
```

and

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\Session Manager\Environment\windir
```

But still not luck. Has anyone seen this behavior before?

forgot to mention this is on windows 7 Enterprise ed

Comment: Don't know what windows version you use or about other windows versions but in XP it's HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment   and HKCU\Environment

Comment: suppose you do for example C:\>reg query HKCU\Environment <ENTER>  or rather C:\>reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment  <ENTER>   Then does it show the environment variable has been changed at that registry location?

Comment: and for me, (xp), %windir% gives c:\windows and %systemroot% gives c:\windows

Comment: I would just reinstall your operating system. Of course I don't see the problem, %WINDIR% is suppose to point to the Windows directory is it not? Both variables are suppose to point to `C:\Windows`

Comment: You changed the value to C:\windows and it did not solve your problems? Maybe this is not what causes your problems then?

Comment: `%systemroot%` and `%windir%` resolve to the same destination to **C:\Windows** on Windows-7 too.

Comment: `echo %windir%`does output C:\windows on my machine, not %SystemRoot%

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check the type of the value you have as `Windir`. You probably inadvertently changed it from `REG_EXPAND_SZ` to `REG_SZ`. 
You have to do it directly in registry (GUI panels will not show you the difference):

Start Registry editor, navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\system\currentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`.
Check that `windir` has a type of  `REG_EXPAND_SZ`.
If not, re-create the entry to be:  `windir      REG_EXPAND_SZ   %SystemRoot%`

**Logoff/logon and check if it works**

Comment: ok this fixed it. In my frustration/stupidity I must have modified the type of the windir reg key to REG_SZ. After re-creating it as an REG_EXPAND_SZ,setting it to %SystemRoot% and restarting %windir% resolved correctly and my shortcuts work again. Thanks a mil for this

Comment: Btw it seems I created an SystemRoot key in the ControlSet002 folder as well when I made this bugger-up, prob in some hope to resolve the problem..so I removed when I re-created the windir key.

Comment: @prayingpantis Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Correction! **`%SystemRoot%` is the default value**. So this variable is set correct in your system.

[image]

Right click on **Computer - Settings - Advanced System Settings - Advanced - Enviroment Variables**. In the second part of that window (under Enviroment Variables) you can find your variable **windir** pointing to *`%systemroot%`*. Change it to *`%SystemRoot%`*, which is the default value and test if you still get errors.

Comment: Actually most likely the default value is C:\Windows, which HAPPENS TO BE the same as %systemroot%. I don't think the value is %systemroot%. The questioner makes it look like that, and so do you now, but I don't think that's the case at all. Look at the comments to his question e.g. from me about xp, or from avirk on windows 7

Comment: see the image i attached. (Sorry it is in german) When you double-click on the windir-value in system enviroment variables you can see the set value is in fact: %SystemRoot%. But you have to doubleclick it, otherwise you just see the resolved value.

Comment: heh you're right XP too..(double click shows %systemroot%) and looking in the registry with reg.exe, shows  windir      REG_EXPAND_SZ   %SystemRoot%

Comment: @Riscie: I added an English version for you ;)

Comment: Thx sir! :) @OliverSalzburg