# After remote desktop, target PC some shortcuts don't work, possibly loses %windir%

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, windows-explorer

I ran into a problem on a PC a few months ago and have really now got to look at (partly because I thought it was due to a failing stick of RAM that was causing BSODs).

My PC runs Windows 7 x64

When I remote desktop to this PC, I noticed some of the shortcuts in my taskbar didn't work, specifically:

- Explorer: "Can't open this item.  It may have been moved, deleted..." etc
- Visual Studio 2013: "A problem occurred... ...To fix run devenv.exe /resetsettings"
- SSMS 2012: "Exception has been thrown by the target of the invocation"

Other shortcuts seem fine (e.g. Excel, Outlook, IE, Chrome, Firefox, Notepad++, LINQPad)

When I navigate to the actual program files (e.g. `devenv.exe`) and run them, the same error occurs.

So I've focused on explorer.   If I run `explorer.exe` in the Run prompt it works.   If I run the shortcut property "`%windir%/explorer.exe`" it says that it cannot be found.   If I run "`%windir%`" in explorer or the Run prompt, it says it can't find it.

So I'm wondering if `%windir%` is the problem (for instance, do SSMS and VS have files that they refer to that use that environment variable)?

However, if I set %windir% after it disappears, the problem with starting VS and SSMS,  and Explorer from the taskbar persist.   So I am not sure that %windir% is the problem.

The problem is not just when connected over remote desktop.  Once I have remoted to that PC, when I later return to it in person, it still has the problem.  Only a log off and log on fixes it.

Any thoughts would be most appreciated.

Comment: Can you please check the scheduled tasks? I know there is a remote connection logged on or something like that - maybe that is altering your settings.

Comment: Thanks @cdavid - I've looked through the Scheduled Tasks and can't see anything that particularly jumps out.  There's nothing obviously connected to Remote Connection logging on that I can see.  Thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: I've edited my answer above as I've just tried manually setting `%windir%` *after* the problem with no discernible effect on resolving the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve %windir% / Cannot modify %path% or %path% being reset on boot](http://superuser.com/questions/527728/cannot-resolve-windir-cannot-modify-path-or-path-being-reset-on-boot)

Comment: I wouldn't say the question is a duplicate, but the cause and answer are in the question linked above - thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been fighting with this same issue for a few months.

I finally found the answer to my situation here:

[Cannot resolve %windir% / Cannot modify %path% or %path% being reset on boot](https://superuser.com/questions/527728/cannot-resolve-windir-cannot-modify-path-or-path-being-reset-on-boot)

Summary of the solution: **"make sure your path is < 2048 characters."**

I had installed a trial version of software that added 635 total characters to my path, making it longer than 2048 total characters.  Once I shortened my path, I was able to connect/disconnect without a problem.

Comment: Thanks so much!  This fixed the issue - not sure why you were downvoted (possibly the formatting - see the edits).   The remote desktop factor in this definitely complicated getting to the bottom of this, so thanks for your answer.