# Rename Windows Install Location?

Tags: windows-10, installation, case-sensitivity

I'm trying to install Matrix SPM software on one of our standard Optiplex desktops for an end user, and I get an error during install "Microsoft Windows must be installed in "C:\WINDOWS". Installation aborted."

I checked our image (Win10 Enterprise LTSC 2019 [equivalent to 1809])and Dell's OEM image (Win 10 Enterprise 21H2), and both use C:\Windows. I checked the vendor-provided PC running XP SP3, and the end-user's personal HP laptop running Win10 Home 21H1, both of which have the software installed successfully, and both of which use C:\WINDOWS.

I know you can change windir in Environment Variables, but the default is %SystemRoot%, not hardcoded C:\Windows, and I hesitate to change references like that. I tried booting to a PE environment and renaming to C:\WINDOWS, but the installer didn't see a difference, presumably because updating the folder name doesn't actually change windir or %SystemRoot%.

Some research led to a guide to making a folder's or drive's contents case sensitive, such that you could have foo.bar and FOO.BAR in the same location, but I worry that system-wide case sensitivity could cause issues for other applications.

Does anyone know a means to either change the case of C:\Windows such that it is visible to applications, or to trick the installer to ignore case sensitivity?

I've looked at [WINDIR environment variable resolves to %SystemRoot% and not C:\windows](https://superuser.com/questions/476965/windir-environment-variable-resolves-to-systemroot-and-not-c-windows) which deals with the same variables I'm trying to change, but that isn't quite the same issue I'm dealing with.

Comment: but is windows actually located in c:\windows?

Comment: @LPChip Windows is installed in C:\Windows on the problem computers, and C:\WINDOWS on the ones where the installer works, per System Information as well as browsing C:\.

Comment: May be some one has accidentally enabled NTFS case sensitivity for the whole C drive or the Windows folder?

Comment: Any app doing a case sensitive comparison on a non case sensitive operating system/file system is a piece of cr*p. This code was probably (poorly) ported from UNIX.  UNIX is cool but has different rules.  One solution.. if you DO have NTFS case sensitivity enabled is to make a junction (or hard link) from C:\Windows to C:\WINDOWS.  This won't work unless enabled.

Comment: Case sensitivity is not currently enabled, I tested this on a freshly imaged PC, as well as a fresh-from-the-OEM Optiplex. I can enable it and set up a symlink, is there likely to be an issue with other applications if case sensitivity is enabled?